# A little rittle

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> A little rittle = 6
> A story of glory = 6
> History of the world = 7
> Just a fairy tail = 5
> Foo = 1
> Riddle a little = 8
> Have fun = 3
> :) = 1
> I will provide hints later = 11
> End = 3
>
> Hint I = 1
> I AM YOU = 0
> i am you = 0
>
> Hint II = 1
> Palindromes are cool = 11
>
> Hint III = 1
> Hint I: BIG = small = 6
> Meaning: small -> BIG = 9
>
> Hint IV = 1
> Mirrors are also cool = 10

Comment: I'm so sry i just missed a piece. I should have checked it earlier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number indicates

> the number of letters that are not symmetric about the vertical axis. All lowercase letters are transformed to uppercase (as indicated in Hint III).

For example:

> `A little rittle` is being transformed to `A LITTLE RITTLE`
>  The letters that change when being mirrored are L, L, E, R, L and E - a total of 6 letters.

Comment: that's correct :)

Answer (score 3):

This works except for the last line (I didn't check all though, is there some more?) :(

Step 1:

> Convert all characters into ASCII values.

Step 2:

> Declare a variable, say ct=0.

Step 3:

> Go through the string. If the ASCII value is even, increment ct by 1

Step 4:

> The RHS is the ct

Comment: thats not the solution, nice try though :)